# Extjs 4 cellEditor plugin Hanlde edit event

Tags: extjs4, cell, editing

There's Ext grid panel with checkbox column.
The purpose is to handle checkbox cell click (which cell clicked & value)

```
Ext.define('App.Model.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',    
    fields: ['Id', 'Login', 'Fio', 'Organization', 'Locked']
});    


    var usrstore = Ext.create('App.Data.Lstore', {
                model: 'App.Model.Users',        
                autoLoad: false,
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: '/Admin/GetUsers'
                }            
            });    

    var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                listeners: { edit: function(editor, e){console.log('gf')} }
            });

            var usrgrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {        
                height: 600,
                store: usrstore,        
                columns: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
                        { dataIndex: 'Login', width: 300, text: 'Логин' },
                        { dataIndex: 'Fio', flex: 1, width: 250, text: 'Фамилия И. О.' },
                        { dataIndex: 'Organization', flex: 2, width: 200, text: 'Организация' },
                        { dataIndex: 'Locked', width: 120, text: 'Блокировка', xtype: 'checkcolumn', align: 'center'}]

            });
```

But no edit event from plugin comes..

What config grid plugin need to start work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your 'cellEditing' in the plugins:[] config. You might also want to specify and editor (text,date,number, etc) on each column that you want to edit. See sencha examples for this stuff. Also checkbox is a Row selector not a cell selector - just something to keep in mind.